# SQL Codeigniter Transaction Rollback Multiple Access Rollback

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have question. What would happen **IF** there are two users are currently using **transaction** that was given by **this** **code**:

```
function upload_csv($filename,$type){
            $source = fopen(base_url().'uploads/'.$filename, 'r') or die("Problem open file");
             $data = fgetcsv($source,","); //1st Line /*DESCRIPTION PART*/
             $data = fgetcsv($source,","); //2nd Line /*DATA START*/
             $this->db->trans_begin();
             $loopflag = true;
             switch($type){     
                case 'receivable':
                                do{
                                    if($data[0]!=""){
                                        $loopflag = $this->csv_parser_receivable($data);
                                    }
                                    if($loopflag==false){break;}
                                }while($data = fgetcsv($source,1000,",")); 
                                break;
                case 'supplier':
                                do{
                                    if($data[0]!=""){
                                        $loopflag = $this->csv_parser_supplier($data);
                                    }
                                    if($loopflag==false){break;}
                                }while($data = fgetcsv($source,1000,",")); 
                                break;


                            }

        if (($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)||($loopflag==false))
        {
            $this->chromephp->log('CANCELLED');
            // $this->chromephp->log("FAIL!! ROLLING BACK TO THE DEEP!");
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->chromephp->log("FINISHED");
            // $this->chromephp->log("SUCCESS! COMMITTING....");
            $this->db->trans_commit();

            $this->consolidate_add($filename,$type);
        }
        $this->db->trans_end();

             fclose($source);
}
```

and then one **user** suddenly **rolls** **back** the database **while** the **other** was **still** **batch-loading** his queries?

Comment: The target object is supposed to stay `locked` for being updated untill the first process is commited or roled back!

Comment: So if these users accessed this would their actions be queued or would they everyone else's transactions rollback while the first user succeeds?

Comment: The most recent data will be available for only reading untill it is released from the first process!

Comment: But if they are accessing different tables, would they be able to insert at the same time?

Comment: In that case each of the multiple processes are waiting for the resources they need to be released, otherwise `deadlocks` occur. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock

Comment: But if the tables they are accessing are independent from each other, can they insert at the same time?

Comment: Yes, if transaction processes are using different tables, objects, etc. , there would be no manipulation conflicts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important property of transactions is that they are isolated. Technically, this means that the execution of transactions has the same effect as running the transactions aerially, one after the next, in sequence, with no overlap in executing any two of them. Such executions are called ***serializable***, meaning “has the same effect as a serial execution.”

The most popular mechanism used to attain serializability is ***`locking`***. The concept is simple:

•
Each transaction reserves access to the data it uses. The reservation is called a
lock
.

•
There are read locks and write locks

•
Before reading a piece of data, a transaction sets a read lock. Before writing the data, it sets a write lock.

•
Read locks conflict with write locks, and write locks conflict with write locks.

•
A transaction can obtain a lock only if no other transaction has a conflicting lock on the same data item. Thus, it can obtain a read lock on x only if no transaction has a write lock on x.

It can obtain a write lock on x only if no transaction has a read lock or write lock on x.
Although the concept of locking is simple, its effects on performance and correctness can be complex, counter-intuitive, and hard to predict. Building robust TP applications requires a solid understanding of locking.